# How to enable 'auto loops' in custom classes?

Tags: c++, loops, class, stl, operator-overloading

I've written a class `vecMatrix` that wraps around `std::vector` to provide two-dimensional storage functionalities. However, while it's incredibly convenient to be able to write loops that sweep the data in an `std::vector` object as

```
std::vector<float> vec;
for (auto& val: vec) { /* do stuff to val*/}
```

I can't do it with my custom class. What kind of operator overload is required to be able to code the same way for `vecMatrix`?:

```
vecMatrix<float> mat;
for (auto& val: mat) { /* do stuff to val*/}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define member functions `begin` and `end` that return iterators to the range that your class represents (or you can define non members that take a reference to your class as arguments.